# mondodb $regex for Mobile Number with or without country code

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to find some records from `mongodb` 
I have some number 3333333333 stored in db and I want to find it by +913333333333
I am not able to find actual query, I have tried but not finding records 3333333333 by +913333333333. pls let me know.

Comment: Not clear with your question. Can you show the code what you done upto now?

Comment: db.getCollection('event').find({"participants.number":{'$regex':'.*+913333333333.*'}})

Comment: you want numbers without country codes. Any number or only 3333333333‌ ?

Comment: yes but i have numbers with country codes and i wants to find records having numbers and numbers with country code

i am not able to find proper like query

Comment: try this regex  `^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([0-9]{10})$`

Comment: db.getCollection('event').find({"participants.number":{'$regex':'^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([0-9]{10})+913333333333$'}})

should i have to use as above?

Comment: Just this `db.getCollection('event').find({"participants.number":{'$regex':'^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([0-9]{10})$'}})`

Comment: it is finding all records i wants to find particular record from  many records

Answer (score 0):

May not be the perfect solution. but it works as of now.

```
    var numberFilterArray = [number.slice(-10), number.slice(-9), number.slice(-8)];

    db.getCollection('event').find({"participants.number":{$in : numberFilterArray}});
```

Comment: thanks but i wants to find stored value 3333333333 by below query 

db.getCollection('event').find({"participants.number":{'$regex':'^([0|\+[0-9]{1‌​,5})?(+913333333333)$'}})

i wants some code which match 3333333333 from placing +913333333333

Comment: The above example code will give both numbers with or without country code. What's wrong with above query? It will give the records you want for sure.

Comment: sir i have only option  to pass +913333333333 in above query because i am getting value +913333333333 from client to find 333333333 so above is not working :(

Comment: Then slice your number string like this `"+913333333333".slice(-10)` before querying the actual term

Comment: i cannot slice because its depends on country code and number it will not be always 10 digits

Comment: In that case why don't you allow MongoDB to store mobile numbers with only country codes?